# How can I remove extra padding in Pre-Lollipop Custom Fonts?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, custom-font

I am using a Custom font in my app(Gotham_book.ttf), and when I use it in a pre-Lollipop devices it includes a padding bottom that it's not showed in lollipop devices.

I tried to use the property android:includeFontPadding="false" but it didn't give me results. What is happening? Maybe a wrong font file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the question by searching for "Lollipop padding", but my problem is a bit different from OP's: instead of having extra padding on old devices my font (a custom image font, used via Callygraphy) mysteriously gained padding on some new versions (with difference between even "minor" Android versions!). I discovered, that in my case these issues have been caused by the font not having proper values in certain tables, so I had to fix it up myself in [Fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) font editor. See detailed explanations here: http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Line_Spacing.html.

TL;DR: do set contents of OS/2 font table properly. And if nothing else works, you can set corresponding values to zeroes (e.g. no padding) and/or manually adjust positions of font glyphs (Fontforge allows these kinds of operations en masse).